# Android AudioTrack does not play all samples

Tags: android, audiotrack

I'm using `AudioTrack` to play a sequence of sine waves, but when I run it on my HTC M9, it plays only part of the samples, and how long it will play is random. e. g. I have 20 tones to play, but it only plays like 2 to 17.5 tones of them. And yes it even will stop in middle of a tone.

Here is my code, from another answer:

```
    ArrayList<double[]> samples = new ArrayList<>();
    int numSamples = 0;
    for (final ToneSegment seg : sequence) {
        int num =  seg.getDuration() * sampleRate / 1000;
        double[] sample = new double[num];
        for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
            sample[i] = Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * i * seg.getPitch() / sampleRate);
        }
        samples.add(sample);
        numSamples += num;
    }

    byte generatedSnd[] = new byte[2 * numSamples];
    int idx = 0;
    for (double[] sample : samples) {
        for (final double dVal : sample) {
            final short val = (short) ((dVal * 32767));
            generatedSnd[idx++] = (byte) (val & 0x00ff);
            generatedSnd[idx++] = (byte) ((val & 0xff00) >>> 8);
        }
    }

    audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
            sampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, generatedSnd.length,
            AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC);
    audioTrack.write(generatedSnd, 0, generatedSnd.length);
    audioTrack.play();
```

Does anyone have any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely the garbage collection causing this problem. I was writing this code in a method returning immediately, as `audioTrack` object will lose the reference to it. If garbage collection happens during the playback, `audioTrack` will be finalized and stops playing tones. Thus this issue happens occasionally, depending on how active the GC is when playing tones.

So I need to keep the `AudioTrack` object reference until the playback ends. I think there are many ways to do this, but finally I use the simplest way:

```
class Player {
    private static AudioTrack sAudioTrack;
}
```

`MediaPlayer` also has this pitfall, and is how I found the problem since it will write log that it's finalized before released.

Answer (score 3):

You are using AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC that is meant for short sounds and low-latency requirements while you should use AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM. AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM is meant for longer streams, but I do not know how long your samples are. So you can try and change AudioTrack:

```
audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
        sampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
        AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, generatedSnd.length,
        AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
```

Also The AudioTrack requires the buffer size in bytes, a short needs to be multiplied by two to calculate the correct amount of required bytes. You could hack it in like this :

```
audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
        sampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
        AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, generatedSnd.length*2,
        AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
```

Comment: I have tried out MODE_STREAM, but it's the same. My samples only play for 3 to 7 seconds.

Comment: They play for a random duration? Have you tried shorter or other audio samples? And have you multiplied the amount of bytes too?

Comment: Yes, I have tried other samples. They are not random duration. What is to multiplied the amount of bytes?

Comment: generatedSnd.length*2?

Comment: It does not work. Also, this code works sometimes, but not other times.

Comment: I play the same samples several times, sometimes it will play through the end, but sometimes it will stop before through the end. If it's a 5 seconds clip, it can stop and any length like 0.5 sec, 1 sec, 4 sec, etc.

Comment: Can you expand your code so that I am able to fully run the part that plays an audio sample? And maybe get a sample audio file so that I can try to fix this for you?

Comment: ToneSegment class just contains two fields, duration and pitch. It's a long stack call so I can't provide standalone runnable code, but for example there will be 26 ToneSegment and each is 128ms, with pitch like 1828, 1875, 1968, 1031, 1078, 1125, 1171...and so on.